# Filter out large number from list in prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to write a function which filters a list of numbers by removing everything less than or equal to a specific number.  The function will take two parameters: a list of numbers and the number to filter.  The function should returns a list which has all the numbers larger than the filter number.

Sometime like this:

```
filter_num_list(L1,N,L2) :- ...

test_filter_num_list :- filter_num_list([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],5,[5,6,7,8,9]).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like:

```
filter_num_list([],N,[]) :- true.  
filter_num_list([H|T],N,[H|S]) :- H > N,filter_num_list(T,N,S).  
filter_num_list([H|T],N,S) :- N >= H, filter_num_list(T,N,S).
```

Answer (score 5):

See also library predicates like include/3 and exclude/3:

```
?- include(=<(5), [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], Is).
Is = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9].
```

Comment: I didn't know about `exclude/3` and `include/3`, very useful, thanks.

Comment: `include/3` and `exclude/3` are library predicates in just a **few** Prolog systems. But this is a generic Prolog question with no indication of the system used. If you want to provide an answer that only works in some systems, at least list those systems.

Comment: I recommend Richard O'Keefe's [document](http://www.cs.otago.ac.nz/staffpriv/ok/pllib.htm) for a nice list of such elementary library predicates, including useful definitions.

Comment: The ROK's reference is a good one to add to the answer itself. But not necessarily a reference that a Prolog newbie will find by him/herself.

Comment: The document is one of the first hits when searching the web for: "include/3 Prolog".

Answer (score 2):

With [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`tfilter/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30211229/4609915) and the reified [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) constraint [`(#<)/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30034258/4609915), you can keep up [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity) and express what you want in no time!

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

Here's a query that I ran with [SWI-Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/) version 7.1.37:

```
?- tfilter(#<(5),[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],Xs).
Xs = [6,7,8,9].                             % succeeds deterministically
false.
```

As the code is **monotone**, we can also ask more general queries and get logically sound answers.

```
?- tfilter(#<(7),[A,B,C],Xs).
Xs = [],      A in inf..7, B in inf..7, C in inf..7 ;
Xs = [C],     A in inf..7, B in inf..7, C in 8..sup ;
Xs = [B],     A in inf..7, B in 8..sup, C in inf..7 ;
Xs = [B,C],   A in inf..7, B in 8..sup, C in 8..sup ;
Xs = [A],     A in 8..sup, B in inf..7, C in inf..7 ;
Xs = [A,C],   A in 8..sup, B in inf..7, C in 8..sup ;
Xs = [A,B],   A in 8..sup, B in 8..sup, C in inf..7 ;
Xs = [A,B,C], A in 8..sup, B in 8..sup, C in 8..sup ;
false.
```

Comment: CLP(FD) is a library only available in a **few** Prolog systems. But this is a generic Prolog question with no indication of the system used. If you want to provide an answer that only works in some systems, at least list those systems.

Comment: You're the one providing the answer. Why not simply listing the Prolog system or systems where you tested it?