# Prolog, split list into two lists

Tags: prolog

I got a problem with lists. What I need to do is to split one list `[1,-2,3,-4]`, into two lists `[1,3]` and `[-2,-4]`. My code looks like the following:

```
lists([],_,_).
lists([X|Xs],Y,Z):- lists(Xs,Y,Z), X>0 -> append([X],Y,Y) ; append([X],Z,Z).
```

and I'm getting

```
Y = [1|Y],
Z = [-2|Z].
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this:

```
domains
    list=integer*

predicates
    split(list,list,list)
clauses
    split([],[],[]).
    split([X|L],[X|L1],L2):-
        X>= 0,
        !,    
        split(L,L1,L2).

    split([X|L],L1,[X|L2]):-
        split(L,L1,L2).
```

> Output :

**Goal:** split([1,2,-3,4,-5,2],X,Y) 
**Solution:** X=[1,2,4,2], Y=[-3,-5]

See, if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

If your Prolog system offers [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) you could preserve [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity). Want to know how? **Read on!**

We take the second definition of `lists/3` that @CapelliC wrote in 
[his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28261657/4609915) as a starting point, and replace `partition/4` by [`tpartition/4`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29867514/4609915) and `(<)/2` by [`(#<)/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30034258/4609915):

```
lists(A,B,C) :- tpartition(#<(0),A,B,C).
```

Let's run a sample query!

```
?- As = [0,1,2,-2,3,4,-4,5,6,7,0], lists(As,Bs,Cs).
As = [0,1,2,-2,3,4,-4,5,6,7,0],
Bs = [  1,2,   3,4,   5,6,7  ],
Cs = [0,    -2,    -4,      0].
```

As we use monotone code, we get logically sound answers for more general queries:

```
?- As = [X,Y], lists(As,Bs,Cs).
As = [X,Y], Bs = [X,Y], Cs = [   ], X in   1..sup, Y in   1..sup ;
As = [X,Y], Bs = [X  ], Cs = [  Y], X in   1..sup, Y in inf..0   ;
As = [X,Y], Bs = [  Y], Cs = [X  ], X in inf..0  , Y in   1..sup ;
As = [X,Y], Bs = [   ], Cs = [X,Y], X in inf..0  , Y in inf..0   .
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you have. It splits a list, and does not matter if have odd or even items number.

```
div(L, A, B) :-
    append(A, B, L),
    length(A, N),
    length(B, N).

div(L, A, B) :-
    append(A, B, L),
    length(A, N),
    N1 is N + 1,
    length(B, N1).

div(L, A, B) :-
    append(A, B, L),
    length(A, N),
    N1 is N - 1,
    length(B, N1).
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for variety, this can also be done with a DCG, which is easy to read for a problem like this:

```
split([], []) --> [].
split([X|T], N) --> [X], { X >= 0 }, split(T, N).
split(P, [X|T]) --> [X], { X < 0 }, split(P, T).

split(L, A, B) :-
    phrase(split(A, B), L).
```

As in:

```
| ?- split([1,2,-4,3,-5], A, B).

A = [1,2,3]
B = [-4,-5] ? ;

no
```

It also provides all the possible solutions in reverse:

```
| ?- split(L, [1,2,3], [-4,-5]).

L = [1,2,3,-4,-5] ? ;

L = [1,2,-4,3,-5] ? ;

L = [1,2,-4,-5,3] ? ;

L = [1,-4,2,3,-5] ? ;

L = [1,-4,2,-5,3] ? ;

L = [1,-4,-5,2,3] ? ;

L = [-4,1,2,3,-5] ? ;

L = [-4,1,2,-5,3] ? ;

L = [-4,1,-5,2,3] ? ;

L = [-4,-5,1,2,3] ? ;

(2 ms) no
```

Gaurav's solution will also do this if the cut is removed and an explicit `X < 0` check placed in the third clause of the `split/3` predicate.

Answer (score 0):

There are several corrections to be done in your code.
If you enjoy compact (as readable) code, a possibility is

```
lists([],[],[]).
lists([X|Xs],Y,Z) :-
  ( X>0 -> (Y,Z)=([X|Ys],Zs) ; (Y,Z)=(Ys,[X|Zs]) ), lists(Xs,Ys,Zs).
```

But since (SWI)Prolog offers libraries to handle common list processing tasks, could be as easy as

```
lists(A,B,C) :- partition(<(0),A,B,C).
```