# Split list in prolog, produce two separate lists

Tags: list, prolog

The Question:

> Define a predicate split/4 which, when provided with a list L and integer N returns two lists, A and B, where A contains the items in L that are greater than or equal to N and B contains the items that are lower than N.

Sample query with expected result:

```
?- split([1, 5, 2, 3, 4], 3, A, B).
A = [5, 3, 4],
B = [1, 2].
```

My code:

```
spit([], 0, [], []).
split([I|Is], N, [A|As], [_B|Bs]):-
    I >= N,
    A is I,
    split(Is, N, As, Bs).
split([I|Is], N, [_A|As], [B|Bs]):-
    I < N,
    B is I,
    split(Is, N, As, Bs).
```

Rather than producing `A` and `B` as required, my code simply returns `false`. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Very similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250167/prolog-split-list-into-two-lists).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Near to correct, but some small error.

Line by line:

a)

```
spit([], 0, [], []).
```

typo: spi vs split

The rule says "the split of an empty list by 0 are two empty lists", true, but too restrictive, change it to "the split of empty list is two empty list, no matter the number":

```
split([], _, [], []).
```

b)

```
split([I|Is], N, [A|As], [_B|Bs]):-
    I >= N,
    A is I,
    split(Is, N, As, Bs).
```

"B" remains undefined, even if you start it as _B to supress the warning. Change it to:

```
split([I|Is], N, [I|As], Bs ):-
    I >= N,
    split(Is, N, As, Bs).
```

c)

```
split([I|Is], N, [_A|As], [B|Bs]):-
    I < N,
    B is I,
    split(Is, N, As, Bs).
```

same as previous.

Comment: You are welcome. I must then understand you have verified it and give the question as closed?

Comment: Really should use `A = I` and `B = I` rather than `A is I` and `B is I` since the `is/2` is intended to arithmetic expression evaluation, not unification.

Comment: Both, A=I and A is I was not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to `partition/4`, use
[`tpartition/4`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29867514/4609915) together with [`(#=<)/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30059035/4609915), like this:

```
?- tpartition(#=<(3),[1,5,2,3,4],As,Bs).
As = [5,3,4], Bs = [1,2].
```

Thanks to [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) and
[`(#=<)/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30059035/4609915), you can run queries that are a lot more general!

For details, look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30059035/4609915) to the related question
"[Splitting a list of integers into a list of positive integers and a list of negative integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547062/splitting-a-list-of-integers-into-a-list-of-positive-integers-and-a-list-of-nega)".

Comment: Please show how this would look like with `(#=<)/3`.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's homework, because, with SWI-Prolog, you have partition/4

> partition(:Pred, +List, ?Included, ?Excluded)      [det]
>
> > Filter  elements  of List  according  to Pred.
> >     True  if  Included  contains all elements  for which call(Pred, X) 
> >     succeeds and Excluded contains the remaining elements.

```
split(L, N, A, B) :-
    partition( =<(N), L, A, B).
```

Comment: +1. Because it is very questionable what it is that a student learns by writing bad implementation of already solved problems.