# Sum up a list using Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, clpfd

I want to sum all list elements greater than some given number. Here's the description:

> `sumup(L, N, GREATN, GEN)` sums up the members of list `L` which are greater than `GREATN` to a variable `N` and puts these members into the list `GEN`.
>
> Sample query:
>
> ```
> ?- sumup([8, 6, 10, 3, 9, 12], N, 7, GEN).
> GEN = [8, 10, 9, 12],                             % expected answer
> N = 39.                                           % 8+10+9+12 = 39
> ```

Following is my code:

```
sum_list([], 0).
sum_list([H|T], Sum) :- 
    H > 3,
    sum_list(T, Rest),
    Sum is H + Rest.
sum_list([H|T], Sum) :-
    H < 3,
    write('').
```

I've tried the recursive way but I failed. How can I fix it?

Comment: Please put your code into the question instead of posting a picture.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your question and your code, I noticed a few things:

- While you speak of "numbers" several times, your samples are integer-only. May we neglect non-integer numbers (float, rational) and handle integers only? I guess so.
- There is an auto-loaded SWI-Prolog [`library(lists)`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=lists) predicate `sum_list/2`.
   
  Calling your predicate `sum_list/2` is an unfortunate choice. 
  Let's pick another name!
- Your definition of `sum_list/2` comprises three clauses:

  1. `sum_list([], 0).`
     Okay!
  2. `sum_list([H|T], Sum) :- H > 3, sum_list(T, Rest), Sum is H + Rest.`

     Notice `H > 3`? Why hardcode the constant integer `3`?
  3. `sum_list([H|T], Sum) :- H < 3, write('').`

     - That clause is not recursive. We need to see all list elements to calculate the sum, not stop at the first list element `H` that fulfills `H < 3`!
     - What's the use of `write('')`? I don't see any.
     - What good is the goal `H < 3`? Like above, why hardcode the integer `3`?
     - Clause #2 covers `H > 3`. Clause #3 covers `H < 3`. **What about `H = 3`?**

---

In this answer we use [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd), which is present in [swi-prolog](/questions/tagged/swi-prolog).

Here's a straight-forward definition of `sumup/4` based on [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd). While it *could* be improved in several ways (better determinism, accumulator-style, possibly some clever redundant constraints could also help), but for the time being it's a nice first shot:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

sumup([], 0, _, []).
sumup([Z|Zs], S0, P, [Z|Xs]) :-
   Z  #> P,
   S0 #= S+Z,
   sumup(Zs, S, P, Xs).
sumup([Z|Zs], S, P, Xs) :-
   Z #=< P,
   sumup(Zs, S, P, Xs).
```

Sample query as given by the OP:

```
?- sumup([8,6,10,3,9,12], N, 7, GEN).
   N = 39, GEN = [8,10,9,12]             % expected answer
;  false.                                % leftover useless choicepoint
```

Comment: I really appreciate your method and your help. It helps a lot.

Comment: @false. Thx for the tip. Will do an answer like `tfilter(#<(P), Zs, GEN), sum(GEN,#=,N)`.

Answer (score 2):

No need to write recursive code! Just use [`tfilter/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29963476/4609915), [`(#<)/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30034258/4609915), and [`clpfd:sum/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sum/3) like this:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

sumup(Zs, S, P, Xs) :-
   tfilter(#<(P), Zs, Xs),
   sum(Xs, #=, S).
```

Sample query:

```
?- sumup([8,6,10,3,9,12], S, 7, Xs).
S = 39, Xs = [8,10,9,12].                       % expected result
```

Note that above query succeeds deterministically—a clear improvement over [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34465685/4609915)!

---

**Bonus!** As the implementation of `sumup/4` is *monotonic*, we *know* that the solution of above query is also part of the solution set of every generalization of the query. Look for yourself!

```
?- sumup([8,6,10,3,9,12], S, E, Xs).
   S = 48, E in inf..2  , Xs = [8,6,10,3,9,12]
;  S = 45, E in   3..5  , Xs = [8,6,10,  9,12]
;  S = 39, E in   6..7  , Xs = [8,  10,  9,12]  % <==== solution of above query
;  S = 31, E in   8..8  , Xs =     [10,  9,12]
;  S = 22, E in   9..9  , Xs =     [10,    12]
;  S = 12, E in  10..11 , Xs =            [12]
;  S =  0, E in  12..sup, Xs =              []
;  false.
```

Answer (score 1):

In SWI-Prolog you can use a [fold](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=foldl/4) and simply query:

```
L=[8, 6, 10, 3, 9, 12], include(<(7),L,Gen), foldl(plus,Gen,0,N).
```

so that `sumup` would be written as

```
sumup(L,N,GreatN,Gen) :-
    include(<(GreatN),L,Gen),
    foldl(plus,Gen,0,N).
```

[`plus/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=plus/3) is an arithmetic predicate that works well in our case.

Comment: Why not use `sum_list/2` instead of `foldl(plus)`?

Comment: @repeat: you're right, `sum_list` would be nice here.

Comment: Actually, these two have different behavior in corner cases. cf. http://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/Sumup_a_b.swinb

Comment: @repeat: right! [`sum_list` uses `is/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/home/swipl/lib/swipl/library/lists.pl?show=src#sum_list/2) whereas `plus/3` checks that the arguments are integers.